# ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'xxxx.app/app/tns_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v47-darwin-x64/fse.node'

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript, hybrid-mobile-app

I am having issues with Build on X Code. I am getting this error.

> ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'xxxx.app/app/tns_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v47-darwin-x64/fse.node' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."

Comment: what do nativescript's devDependencies have to do with your question?

Comment: I think some dev dependency got into the app by mistake which were not supposed to be and they are causing problem. Please refer-   https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2032

Comment: i doubt it, devDependencies are for the editor/cli only, they arent compiled into the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this error is that one of my dev Dependencies was inside dependencies object in package.json file.

As fse.node is related with "nativescript-dev-sass": "^1.0.0-rc.2" I just moved it from dependecies to devDependencies and error was gone.

Comment: I just had the same problem, but upon reading package-lock.json, I found it was caused by webpack being in app dependencies instead of dev dependencies.